# Verify if a Dynamically Loaded Image has Completed in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am calling this "display" function in Vue.js, which loads an image. I am using img.onload in order to verify when the image has completed its loading. However, the code never reaches the console.log line. What am I missing?

```
<input type="button" name="display" value="Display" v-on:click="display" />

display () {
  var img = new Image()
  img.onload = function () {
    console.log('Loaded')
  }
  img.src = '../Image.jpg'
}
```

Thank you. J

Comment: Are you sure that your image has been loaded? Have you double-checked the src?

Comment: Thank you @KienHT The source is indeed accurate. No, I am not sure if the image has actually completed its loading in the DOM (I am loading it dynamically), which is why I am verifying this event using img.onload. Isn't this how it is supposed to be done?

Comment: I think the problem is the relative path. I'm pretty sure that if you use an absolute path, like this google image for example, https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_92x30dp.png, it will work just fine

Comment: Are you using Webpack for bundling?

Comment: Thank you @KienHT Yes, I am using Webpack. I have "solved" the issue by creating the image beforehand and hiding it when  the page loads. Thank you for your help.

Comment: That's a nice workaround. You could take a look at this page, I think it's related to your problem with dynamic image loading which happens at runtime, https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/issues/126